# How to save data to internal storage in android app persistently between updates?

Tags: android, save, storage, internal

My android app saves user information as serialized objects in a ".ser" file that's saved to internal storage. 
The data can be stored and retrieved and written just fine but whenever the user installs an update to the app, all the data is erased. 
I assume the file is deleted upon installation of an update.
My question is: how do I save data to internal storage without it getting deleted when users install updates?
Do I have to use a different method, like SharedPreferences or SQLite?
or can my FileOutputStream save persistently through updates?

Answer (score 0):

If you're worried about it getting deleted on internal memory, why not write to the ext?

Answer (score 0):

Hello Boron I've been using `SharedPreferences` for the purpose you are explaining. I don't think SQLite would be preferable because you might want to save the images and large information like Bio of the user.

I store all my user data in shared preference and I am almost positive that the data persists even on updating the application. This should solve your problem.

When you have to store the images I would suggest you to convert the image to base 64 or some string and store in `SharedPreferences` this reduces the chances of deleting of the image from mobile by user accidentally.

**Happy Coding**